# Xamarin - Frame.GestureRecognizers doesn't work when tapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer, frame

I have a Xamarin project with a view of a product's details. I have two buttons which can increase or decrease the quantity of the product. To show how it changes I have a label named `lblQuantity` which shows the quantity and it's updated if you tap on the remove or add button.

To have some context here's the view

[image]

The issue is that the `lblQuantity` isn't updating itself. I had previously another view with a stacklayout and the gesture recognizers worked fine. Now it doesn't even go inside the method.

Here's the xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:AppCrijoya.Controls"
             x:Class="AppCrijoya.Views.ProductDetailPage">

    <ScrollView>

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" Spacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- 1. Profile picture-->

                <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" CornerRadius="20">
                    <Image x:Name="ProductImage" Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="230"/>
                </Frame>
                <!-- Here add the code that is being explained in the next block-->
                <StackLayout  HeightRequest="90" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Start">

                    <StackLayout Padding="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <!-- Here add the code that is being explained in the next block-->
                        <!-- Blocks: 3 and 4 -->
                        <Grid Padding="25,5,25,0" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Here add the code that is being explained in the next block-->
                            <!-- 4. Contact information-->
                            <Label x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="30" TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label x:Name="txtDescription" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" TextColor="Black" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Padding="0,10,0,0" FontSize="16">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="Stock: " FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                                        <Span x:Name="txtDetails" TextColor="black"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <!--4. Contact information: Board inforation-->
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Quantity" FontAttributes="Bold" Style="{StaticResource stlBoardTitle}" />

                            <Frame  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource stkCart}">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="RemoveTap" Tapped="RemoveTap_Tapped"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label Text="-" Style="{StaticResource lblCart}"/>
                            </Frame>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"  HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                <Label 
                                   x:Name="lblQuantity" 
                                   Text="1" 
                                   FontSize="17"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   HeightRequest="40"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <Frame Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource stkCart}">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="AddTap" Tapped="AddTap_Tapped"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label Text="+" Style="{StaticResource lblCart}"/>
                            </Frame>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
            <controls:MyFrame HasShadow="true" HeightRequest="80" BackgroundColor="#e5d3c2" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <StackLayout WidthRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            x:Name="txtPrice"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                            TextColor="White"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="25"
                            />
                        <Button CornerRadius="30" 
                        x:Name="btnAddToCart"
                        Clicked="BtnAddToCart_Clicked"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        TextColor="Black" 
                        Text="Añadir al carrito" 
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        Style="{StaticResource btn}" 
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </controls:MyFrame>

        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's the Add and Remove method that I know work fine

```
private void RemoveTap_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(lblQuantity.Text);

            if (quantity > 1)
            {
                quantity -= 1;
            }

            lblQuantity.Text = quantity.ToString();
        }
        private void AddTap_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(lblQuantity.Text);
            quantity += 1;
            lblQuantity.Text = quantity.ToString();
        }
```

The text of the label is supossed to be changed but it isn't. And as I said it doesn't even enter on the method.

I don't know what's the issue. Please help and thanks.

**EDIT**

I have tried changing it for a `Button` but still doesn't work. I thought it might be a problem with the grid but I still don't know.

Comment: try attaching the gesture to the Label instead of the Frame

Comment: @Jason doesn't work either. I think the issue is with the stacklayout and grid but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by making sure the frames where inside the StackLayout as they weren't before

Here is an image to explain it

[image]

The frames to add or remove weren't inside the red StackLayout so the tap gesture recognizer wouldn't do anything. I just gave it more height and set the Aspect to `FillAndExpand`