# TapGestureRecognizer not working on Xamarin.Forms Android (working fine on iOS)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have the following code in my Xamarin.Forms app...

```
     <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource 
AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:VehicleAlarmViewModel2}}, 
Path=NavigateToLocationCommand}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding Location}" />
```

This works as expected in iOS but when tested in an Android emulator (Pixel 5 API 30) it seems to ignore the tap. The command's method is never reached.

Is this a known issue? Am I doing something wrong (wouldn't surprise me!)? Suggestions?

Comment: knowing the layout the tap is attached to would be helpful

Comment: I'm with Jason here. Some more code might indeed be helpful. Maybe also show the command in the ViewModel. It's unusual that it works on one platform and not on another when it comes to bindings and commands.

Comment: ` private Command _navigateToLocationCommand;
 public ICommand NavigateToLocationCommand => 
     _navigateToLocationCommand ??= 
         new Command(async param => await NavigateToLocation(param));`

I can't seem to get the formatting right in comments. In any case, NavigateToLocation takes the string passed in above and uses it to parse out longitude and latitude.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the control code in the xaml about using the TapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain what you mean by the control code in the xaml?

Comment: Which kind of the control did you use the TapGestureRecognizer? An image or a frame or the others?

Comment: It is a class derived from our custom userControl which in turn derives from Frame. 

The files are large so I'm providing links to GoogleDocs that contain the code...

LineItemView.xaml:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U4zKRCLlyHnbhXa84nqOPewfD95JAnBvW-JO84oiW7g/edit?usp=sharing

LineItemView.xaml.cs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l5UpXgZMs05cP4OERhm1_HMsPv_EJQQgzY8xu97aayY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this. Please note that the tap gesture recognizer *does* work on iOS but not on Android.

Thanks again
Jesse

Comment: I can't find the TapGestureRecognizer from the code you provided. But [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696966/xamarin-frame-gesturerecognizers-doesnt-work-when-tapped) have the similar problem which TapGestureRecognizer does't work on the frame, it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for Android, I need to add

```
InputTransparent = "True"
```

to the Grid. I do not know why this works, nor why it isn't needed by iOS, but it does fix the problem.